# Keep tabs position while PostBack c# jQuery 1.10

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a page containing a jQuery ui tab control. That is working just fine.
The issue I have is saving the selected tab between PostBacks occuring from a DropDownList, without (offcourse) disabling those PostBacks.

I have following code on my aspx page and I receive no Javascript errors whatsoever:

```
<script>
    var selected_tab = 1;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var tabs = $("#rapportentabs").tabs({
            activate: function (e, i) {
                selected_tab = i.index;
            }
        });
        selected_tab = $("[id$=selected_tab]").val() != "" ? parseInt($("[id$=selected_tab]").val()) : 0;
        tabs.tabs("option", "active", selected_tab);
        $("form").submit(function () {
            $("[id$=selected_tab]").val(selected_tab);
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="rapportentabs">//containing the tabs itself</Div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="selected_tab" runat="server" />
```

I have following in my code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selected_tab.Value = Request.Form[selected_tab.UniqueID];
}
```

I've finally found a solution which seems to work perfectly

Just change the javascript part using direct reference to objects and use i.newTab.index() instead of i.index

The correct script should read as:

```
<script>
    var selected_tab = 1;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var tabs = $("#rapportentabs").tabs({
            activate: function (e, i) {
                selected_tab = i.newTab.index();
                $("#selected_tab").val(selected_tab);
            }
        });
        selected_tab = $("#selected_tab").val() != "" ? parseInt($("#selected_tab").val()) : 0;
        tabs.tabs("option", "active", selected_tab);
        $("form").submit(function () {
            $("#selected_tab").val(selected_tab);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What's the length of $("[id$=selected_tab]")? is it finding it?

Comment: Length of $("[id$=selected_tab]") is 1, it's value allthough always returns an empty string

Answer (score 0):

One option is to save the selected_tab in a localstorage and then restore it when the page loads - this will have a side affect of saving the selected tab not only when you post but also when you close the tab and reopen it.

Another option, much better IMHO, is to post the form with Ajax and this way you will not get a page refreshed at all - but this will mean you have to update whatever page changes, which may be lots of work if you have lots of server side rendering code.